# A functional approach in R to apply a function to a data frame that uses input from each column of another data frame

Tags: r, dictionary

I want to apply a linear approximation to all elements in a data frame based on a lookup table.

I am able to do this for one lookup table, but I would need a functional approach (i.e. `map` or `apply`) to apply this multiple times for a number of lookup tables, which are written in one data frame.

I have data frame `A`, such that

```
A <- data.frame(cbind(c(2,2,1),c(1,1,2),c(2,1,2)))
```

and a table of lookup values `Z`

```
Z <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2),c(0.25,0.5)))
```

which I want to use as basis for linear interpolation for values in data frame `A`.

I can write a function that interpolates the values in `A` based on values in `Z`, such that

```
approximate <- function(x) approx(x=Z[,1], y=Z[,2], xout=x)$y
```

and apply it to the all elements in `A`

```
library(purrr)
as.data.frame(purrr::map(A, approximate))
```

How would I do this for more than one columns in `Z`, for example

```
Z1 <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2),c(0.25,0.5),c(0.5,1)))
```

The desired output would be two lists that each contain a data frame of size `A` that applies the `approximate` function for each column of `Z1[,-1]`,  `c(0,25,0.5), c(0.5,1), ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `approximate()` function to include an argument for which column of `Z1[, -1]` to use for `y`. You can then have an outer `map()` over `Z1[, -1]` and an inner `map_dfr()` (equivalent to `as.data.frame(map())` in this context) over `A`. For example:

```
library(purrr)

approximate <- function(xout, y, x) approx(x, y, xout)$y
    
map(Z1[, -1], function(y) map_dfr(A, approximate, y, Z1[, 1]))
```